# Div elements not spanning full-width of Bourbon neat grid

Tags: html, css, sass, bourbon, neat

Not sure why my div elements are not spanning the full width of my bourbon grid. The process only happens for the last two divs. **see image**.  Why does it behave in this way? Experiencing a similar issue on [codepen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/NrqBjv). Why aren't the div elements occupying the full grid?

[image]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="main-container">
       <div class="articles">
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
            <article></article>
            <article></article>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .articles{
  @include outer-container;

    article {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $lightest-grey;

        img{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        } 

        span{
            color: $light-grey;
        }
    }
}


@include media ($tablet) {

article{
    @include span-columns(3 of 6);
}

}
```

Solution: I had to add  `@include omega(2n)`. I'm not sure if this is a good method but will suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

Omega just

> Removes the element's gutter margin, regardless of its position in the
> grid hierarchy or display property. It can target a specific element,
> or every nth-child occurrence. Works only with block layouts.
>
> [Source](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#omega)

Try removing the gutter margin from elements. And don't forget about margins on `body` element.

Comment: I removed margin/padding from body yet the same thing happens. Have a look and comment out omega in this pen -http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/NrqBjv

Comment: What I meant by removing gutter margins is that every div in your pen has `margin-right` property set around 2.35%. In order for the three columns to fit into this grid, you will need to set `margin-right: 0;` property on every third element.

You can find edited pen here:
[link](http://codepen.io/Cordo-van-Saviour/pen/rLVqEd)